# Llamar un metodo desde otro metodo en el mismo controlador

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
export const getCountryByNumeric_code = (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id ?? req.body.id;

    if(!id) return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Id required' });

    Country.find({'iso_code.numeric_code': id}, (err, country) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Petition ERROR' });
        }
        if(!country) return res.status(204).json({ message: 'Not found' });

        return res.status(200).json({ country: country });
    })
}
```

Basicamente, lo que hace es buscar un pais por un ID determinado en la base de datos de mongo.

Lo que necesito hacer luego es crear el metodo para crear un pais nuevo pasandole algunos paramentros por el body. Al empezar a crear esta funcion, me encuentro con que tengo que analizar si el pais ya existe en la base de datos, y lo busco por este numeric_code.

Lo puedo hacer, repitiendo el mismo codigo de busqueda, pero me imagino que hay una manera de llamar al primer codigo para que haga la busqueda y de acuerdo al resultado guardar o no el nuevo objeto.

Seria una cosa asi, pero repitiendo codigo. Quisiera poder llamar al metodo anterior si es que se puede.

```
export const newCountry = (req, res) => {

    const params = req.body;

    if(!params.id) return res.status(200).json({message: 'Need to set an ID for the Country'});
    if(!params.name) return res.status(200).json({message: 'Need to set a NAME for the Country'});

        Country.find({'iso_code.numeric_code': params.id}, (err, country) => {
        // console.log(iso_code)
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Petition ERROR' });
        }
        if(!country) return res.status(204).json({ message: 'Not found' });

        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'country already exists' });
    });
    

    return res.status(200).json({message: params.id});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de proceder con malas prácticas en la programación, te recomiendo aplicar modularización, creando una función llamada:

```
const checkCountry = async (numeric_code) => {
    const country = await Country.find({'iso_code.numeric_code': numeric_code})
    if(country) return true;
    return false;
})
```

La cual consumas en tus demás métodos.

También te recomiendo empezar a trabajar con los bloques **try...catch**, harán tu código mucho más sencillo y se logran algunas cuantas mejorías, en vez de sobrellenar el código de callbacks.

Un detalle más a recalcar, es que revises los códigos de estados de respuestas en tu aplicación, estás haciendo uso equivocado de ellos.

Cuando estás teniendo un problema de error en petición, en este caso, cuando ocurre un error en tu callback de la función de búsqueda estás retornando un '**404**' cuando debería ser un '**500**' mínimo.

También puede verse cuando retornas un '**200**' cuando tu petición (request) no posee algún parámetro, se usa habitualmente el código '**400**' ya que es una 'mala petición' (no cumple con lo que es requerido para procesarla).

Y finalmente, el '**204**' que estás utilizando, es más utilizado cuando se realiza un 'update' (actualización), pero en estos casos al no encontrar un elemento, lo más propio es utilizar el conocido '**404**'.